# While copying a pointer, is the memory copied as well?

Tags: c

Consider the code below:

```
int * a = malloc(sizeof *a * 10);
int * b;
b = a;   //Is there an operation  "b = malloc(sizeof *a * 10);" occuring?
free(b);    //will the memory of 'a' be free?
```

Also, how can I test whether a piece of memory is released or not?

Comment: Simple answer: no, the memory is not copied.

Comment: The whole point of pointers is that you can use them to refer to the same memory without copying it.

Comment: That's why you can use a pointer parameter in a function so it can modify the caller's data.

Comment: There's no way to test whether memory has been freed. The application has to keep track itself.

Comment: Yes, `free(b)` is equivalent to `free(a)`.  The memory is freed in either case.

Comment: When learning C one of the first things you'll need to do is lower your expectations. A lot. Almost *nothing* happens implicitly. You must be explicit in your requests of the language.

Comment: C doesn't track memory allocations. You as the programmer must by establishing the code that "owns" any particular allocation and has the responsibility for releasing it.

Comment: The `free()` function knowns only the pointer value that you pass to it. it has no way of knowing that you assigned the value from `malloc()` to one variable, copied it to another, and used that to send to `free()`, and it isn't relevant. The pointer value is still the same, but afterwards the pointer value held by `a` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `b = a;   //Is there an operation  "b = malloc(sizeof *a * 10);" occuring?`

No, assigning `a` to `b` merely sets `b` to have the value of `a`. Since `a` is a pointer, `b` then points to the same place that `a` points to.

> `free(b);    //will the memory of 'a' be free?`

Yes, after `b = a;`, `free(b);` will free the memory that `a` points to. Note that this is not the memory **of** `a`, it is the memory `a` **points to**. C does not create or maintain any connection or ownership relation between a pointer and the memory it points to. Pointers are merely things with values that are addresses.

The fact that memory was initially allocated and assigned to `a` with `a = malloc(…)` does not create any special relationship between `a` and the memory. Other pointers can be used to access and free the memory, and the value of `a` can be changed to something entirely unrelated without affecting the memory.

Comment: I think this is a very clear and precise explanation.

Comment: @zhittty: I did not vote but might guess some people thought this information ought to be obtained by working through a C course or textbook and is not helpful to future readers on Stack Overflow.